# flex how can i use an image multiple times

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, reusability, hdrimages

i want to reuse an image multiple times within an item renderer,

is it possible to embed the image and then reuse multiple times without having to go back to the server for the image? Is this the most performant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could be helpful for you :

[How to Control Flex 3 Image Control Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303054/how-to-control-flex-3-image-control-caching)

it's an old question/answers posted on stackoverflow.